# Multiple strings in alt image text

Tags: php, wordpress-theming

This is a simple question (I think), which is maybe why I can't find it answered already (or simply answered).

I want to display additional info on image hover.  I can display only the title of the image with:
    `alt="<?php echo ($post_detail['post_title']); ?>`

I can change this to display only the year with:
    `alt="<?php echo ($post_detail['year']); ?>`

How do I display BOTH at once? They can be on the same line, or one above the other. It matters little.

Thx for any help, excuse my rudimentary skill level.

Comment: You can add strings together with dot `echo ($post_detail['year'].$post_detail['variable'])` or adding them together `$post_detail['year'] .= $variable2`

Comment: _“I want to display additional info on image hover”_ - the `alt` attribute is the wrong one for that to begin with; you want `title` - go read up on the difference. And the actual question you asked here is about a rather trivial matter, you should rather have been able to research this yourself, or know stuff like this if you worked through an actual beginner’s tutorial. This site is not meant to outsource either of those.

Comment: @misorude The code I am modifying, which contains over 1000 individual scripts uses the alt attribute for that function in too many places to list, so consistency to retain functionality was required. In addition to which time was of the essence, so learning to code from square one was not an option. I do appreciate your explaining the intended use of the site you own though, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can concat the strings easily with, e.g.:

```
alt="<?php echo $post_detail['post_title'] . ' ' . $post_detail['year'] ?>"
```

Or just echo both variables:

```
alt="<?php echo $post_detail['post_title'] ?> <?php echo $post_detail['year'] ?>"
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you! This also helps with a much more involved issue I didn't even know how to explain.  You have helped over 5,000 individuals with one answer.